# The following code and android app stops working

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I am developing an app. When I added the firebase dependency, the app started crashing and the following error indicates the problem. I am unable to understand the problem.

```
2019-03-30 22:16:50.473 4289-4289/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper, PID: 4289
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/zza;
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper.config.admob.initialInterstitial(admob.java:43)
        at com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper-1/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper.config.admob.initialInterstitial(admob.java:43) 
        at com.dhruvbhati.blackwallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I want the app to stop crashing.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.6.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0:15.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

also my project level

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0:15.0.0'
```

is not correct, you should either use the `16.0.0` version or the `15.0.0`

Gennerally gradle importing is the following pattern:

```
<group-id>:<artifact-id>:<version>
```

So this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

or this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
```

Comment: i solved the problem by adding same version of google ads and firebase

Comment: Having `16.0.0:15.0.0` together is not correct anyway.